# Sitecore Custom language causing issue while switching an item in the newly created custom language

Tags: content-editor, multilingual

I have created a new language "en-JP" and used the below entry in LanguageDefinitions.config file

```
<language id="en" region="JP" codepage="65001" encoding="utf-8" charset="iso-8859-1" icon="flags/16x16/flag_Japan.PNG" />
```

But when I switch an item language in Sitecore CMS, it is throwing the below error.

[image: Error Screen]

Could you please suggest to me how we can add this language and I wanted to show en-JP in my url and based on context language we're also pulling search results. Hence it is not recommended to use any alternate language code apart from "en-jp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register custom language in .NET and then try to define that in Sitecore.

Sample code:

```
string culture = "en-JP";
string name = "English (Japanese)";
  
//Create Culture & Region Info with an existing Language Culture (Eg: en-US)
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(culture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(cultureInfo);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(regionInfo);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = name;
                  
//Register the Custom Language Culture
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
```

Check this blog that talks in detail about this - https://subbu.ca/blogs/adding-custom-language-in-sitecore/

There is a Sitecore SE post on this topic [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/4297/172) that might be useful to you.