# Publish Exception on BlobProviderException

Tags: sitecore-client

We are doing `Sitecore 8.1 to 10.2 upgrade`. as a step to sync data we performed Site Publish to move content from Master to the Web database. We are getting this.

[image: error].

We also saw a relevant article: [https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001874 and tried](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001874%20and%20tried)

Solution
As an alternative solution:

Attach a new media to media items with an empty Media field.
Make these media items unpublishable

But it is not solving the issue. Will anyone can you give clear input? Above 2-line solution.

Tried these 2 suggestions as well:
https://sitecorecorner.wordpress.com/2020/07/04/blobstorage-error-while-publishing-media-item - The node already exists.

https://konabos.com/blog/publishing-media-items-throws-error-when-no-media-is-attached - Found 17 Items from view and the same cleared from the item Table.

Please advise.

Error:

---

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. --->
> Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.Abstractions.BlobProviderException: No
> supported provider for is configured.
>
> at
> Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.BlobStorage.GetBlobProvider[T](BlobIdentifier
> identifier)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyBlobField(Field sourceField,
> Item targetVersion)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyBlobFields(Item
> sourceVersion, Item targetVersion)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.TransformToTargetVersion(Item
> sourceVersion)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyToTarget(Item sourceVersion,
> Item originalItem)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersionToTarget(Item
> sourceVersion, Item targetItem, Boolean targetCreated)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersion(Item
> sourceVersion)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext
> context)
>
> at (Object , Object )
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean
> failIfNotExists)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext
> context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
> entry, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
> entries, PublishContext context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(PublishContext
> context)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext
> context)
>
> at (Object , Object )
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean
> failIfNotExists)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext
> context)
>
> at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object
> obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
> Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>
> at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
>
> at (Object , Object )
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean
> failIfNotExists)
>
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>
> at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
>
> at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Thank you,
Gunasekaran

Comment: Error in the screenshot shows "item:saved" event, also couldn't parse the language 'x-en-AE'. Take a look at languages, Also you could try publishing each node one by one to identify items that cause an issue during publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two separate issues. 1) This custom language "x-en-AE" (English - United Arab Emirates?) is not installed / configured in your upgraded solution. And 2) blank or null values in media items.

**1) This custom language**

Suggest reviewing the old installation both in Sitecore (`/sitecore/System/Languages`) and in config (`\App_Config\LanguageDefinitions.config`) and look for references to the "x-en-AE" or to "English - United Arab Emirates". Make sure the same has been applied to upgraded solution.

Also see this for some additional info: [How to add custom lang-region in sitecore system language](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-add-custom-lang-region-in-sitecore-system-language)

**2) Blank or null values in media items**

You mention having followed the suggestions here: https://konabos.com/blog/publishing-media-items-throws-error-when-no-media-is-attached

> and - Found 17 Items from view and the same cleared from the item
> Table.

The deletions you need to be making are from the various **fields** table. Suggest reviewing this again. Run the following commands to check for blank or missing values in ALL field tables (i.e. **versoined / unversioned / shared**).

```
SELECT ItemId FROM [dbo].[SharedFields] where FieldId='{40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}' and [Value] = '' or [Value] is null

SELECT ItemId FROM [dbo].[VersionedFields] where FieldId='{40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}' and [Value] = '' or [Value] is null

SELECT ItemId FROM [dbo].[UnversionedFields] where FieldId='{40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}' and [Value] = '' or [Value] is null
```

If any of the above queries bring back results, delete the associated rows from the tables. Keep doing this until all three of the queries bring back no results.